# URL Query String

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I downloaded the BeRocket AJAX Filter plugin and it has changed the way my url query strings are formatted and now my function for getting product images won't work.

This is how I was getting the query string;

```
<php $filter_colour = $_GET['filter_colour']; ?>
```

This worked fine when my query string was like so;

```
www.website.co.uk/?filter_color=blue&filter_type_of_light=something
```

But now I can only have my query strings like the following by altering the settings in the plugin;

```
www.website.co.uk/?filters=type-of-light[550]|colour[569]
www.website.co.uk/?filters=type-of-light[ceiling-lights]|colour[pink]
www.website.co.uk/filters/type-of-light=ceiling-lights&colour=green
```

How can I still use $_GET to get the value of colour in the url with these links?

There are also these settings in the permalinks tab in wordpress, that I can use to alter the query string;

[image]

[image]

[image]

These are my options in the plugin for the query strings;

[image]

Here is the function where I am using $_GET to get the colour value, I use this function to set the images on the products;

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'set_product_image', 10);

function set_product_image() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        // color of first variation
        $default_image = '';

        foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ){            
            $variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );
            $product_colour = strtolower( $variation->get_attribute('colour') );

            // get first variation
            if( $default_image == '' ){
                $default_image = $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );
            }
            $filter_colour = $_GET['colour'];

            if( $product_colour == $filter_colour){
                // if filter applied, echo and return
                echo $variation->get_image( array(300, 300) );
                return;
            }
        }
        // filter not applied, return default image
        echo $default_image ;
    }

    else if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            echo $product->get_image( array(300, 300) );
        }else{
            echo '<img src="https://website.co.uk/wp-content/themes/dist/images/placeholder.png">';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to get the `colour` part alone?

Comment: Yeah I just want the value(s) of colour

Comment: @user3783243 I was able to slightly modify your code to do what I needed. If you add it as an answer I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Reece I've moved that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two of the example strings you can use a regex to identify the bit you want. For the third example `colour` should be its own index so just grab it as is. For the other two search for the `colour[` then capture everything until the first `]`. This will put the value into `$color` as the `1` index. It is the `1` index because it is the first capture group, the `0` index has the full match. Also if the `u` is optional in `colour` you can add a `?` after it.

```
if(empty($_GET['colour'])){
    if(preg_match('/colour\[(.*?)\]/', $_GET['filters'], $color)){
            echo $color[1] . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
     echo $_GET['colour'];//just for demo purposes, will open XSS injection, escape for real usage
}
```

PHP in action: https://3v4l.org/SbAvR

Answer (score 1):

Stick with this URL structure - `http://www.website.co.uk/?filters=type-of-light[ceiling-lights]|colour[pink]`. You can use regex as @user3783243 suggests or you can use PHP `explode`. This is one of the easiest but not proper way.

```
$colortemp = explode('colour[', $_GET['filters']);
$colortemp1 = explode(']', $colortemp[1]);
$color = $colortemp[0];
```

Then you can replace in your function like `$filter_colour = $color;`.

Hope this helps.